# Map and split values in array

Tags: swift, tuples

How I can map a array and, **in same closure**, split the values in two variables?

This code work, but, I want use only one closure, not three.

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4]

let a = array.map { v -> (Int, Int) in
    (v * 2, v * 10)
}

let x = a.map { $0.0 }
let y = a.map { $0.1 }
```

Comment: I didn't meet your requirement of using a single closure, but I think I have the most concise and preferable solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var x = [Int]()
var y = [Int]()

array.forEach() {
    x.append($0 * 2)
    y.append($0 * 10)
}

print(x[0]) // 2
print(y[0]) // 10
...
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a possibly less readable, but arguably more functional-style solution (immutable arrays, no for-each loop, pure function that only acts on its inputs and doesn't create side effects outside the closure):

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let (x, y) = array.reduce(([Int](), [Int]())){ (result, int) in (result.0 + [int*2], result.1 + [int*10]) }

print(x) // [2, 4, 6, 8]
print(y) // [10, 20, 30, 40]
```

It also meets your requirement of using just one closure

Answer (score 1):

You can use tuple assignment to achieve this:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4]

let (x, y) = (array.map{$0 * 2}, array.map{$0 * 10})

print(x, y)
```